# WCF application automatically restarts

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7

I have a WCF application and its getting restart to frequently.
To know the resaon of restart I have used "**ApplicationShutdownReason**" enum in Application_End method of Global.asax.
The reason I got is "**ConfigurationChange**".
There is nothing in my app_data folder, nor my web.config file is getting updated.
NOTE: Process ID is not getting changed when application restarts.

I want to stop this restarting but not getting which configuration file is getting changed.

Comment: What is the timeout on your application pool?   The default timeout is 20 minutes, so after 20 minutes of activity the app will be shut down.  Also, is the app pool running more than one application?   If it is, it could be another app that is causing the restart.

Comment: @Tim Only one application is running under this app pool. Default timeout is set to 0, that means, its unlimited.

Comment: Is it possible if CPU utilization is reached to near by 100% then application is getting restarted?

Comment: Hmm....possible.  IIS does some funny things with threads and processes sometimes.  Is your service CPU intensive?

Comment: There are many other applications running on this machine. But when I see the CPU utilization is task manager only one application is utilizing the cpu arouund 90%. One thing is getting cleared is that why in appliation_end method shutdown reason is "ConfigurationChange"?

Comment: @Tim Any Suggestions?

Comment: @Tim My application is having on FTP folder and other two folders in which files are created and deleted for the processing. Can this tends to application restart?  NOTE: This folders are not inside app_data folder.